# Selenium webdriver not finding xpath elements

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to grab all the restaurant locations from this website link, but everytime that I do this, it returns a list of empty strings. What could I do actually get the list I need?

```
driver = Chrome(path_to_chrome_driver)
driver.get('https://www.marriott.com/hotels/fact-sheet/travel/CZLMC-Constantine-Marriott-Hotel')
restaurants = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="l-margin-top-none"]')
restaurants = [item.text for item in restaurants]
print(restaurants)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching restaurants like:

```
restaurants = [item.get_property('textContent') for item in restaurants]
```